# Tasks with number of child tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

Scenario is something like this, I have 4 specific URLs in hand, each URL page contains many links to a web page, I need to extract some information of those web pages. I'm planning to use nested task to do this job, Multiple tasks inside one task. Something like below.

```
        var t1Actions = new List<Action>();
        var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (var action in t1Actions)
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(action, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                }
            });

        var t2Actions = new List<Action>();
        var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (var action in t2Actions)
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(action, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                }
            });

        var t3Actions = new List<Action>();
        var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (var action in t3Actions)
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(action, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                }
            });

        var t4Actions = new List<Action>();
        var t4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (var action in t4Actions)
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(action, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                }
            });

        Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
```

Here is my questions:

1. Is this way a good way to do jobs like what I mentioned above?
2. Which one is efficient, replace child tasks with `Parallel.Invoke(action)` or leave it as it is?
3. How should I notify (for example UI) if a nested task completed, Do I have control over nested tasks?

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: No, this is not a good way. You should be using `await` along with the `async` API methods to read information from a web page, e.g. `byte[] urlContents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);`. (See [`HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551751(v=vs.118).aspx))

Comment: "Is this way a good way to do jobs like what I mentioned above?" What happened when you ran the code?   Did it work?

Comment: [Also see this guide from Microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/walkthrough-accessing-the-web-by-using-async-and-await#startButton)

Comment: @Servy I want to hear from expert, I haven't started yet.

Comment: @saber Then start.  Do your research.  Try to solve the problems yourself.  See how well they work.  Ask on SO once you have come across a problem that you can't solve with research or your own attempts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a code review request

Comment: @saber what are you trying to do? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? You described how you thought it can be solved (not like this) but not what the problem is. Why not just create just one list of actions? Why are you looking at "child" tasks?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem isn't how to handle child tasks. It's how to get a list of URLs from some directory pages, retrieve those pages and process them.

This can be done easily using .NET's [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. Each step can be implemented as a block that reads one URL and produces an output.

1. The first block can be a [TransformManyBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194784%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that accepts one page URL and retursn a list of page URLs
2. The second block can be a [TransformBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194782(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts a single page URL and returns its contents
3. The third block can be an Action Block that accepts the page and does whatever is needed with it.

For example:

```
var listBlock = new TransformManyBlock<Uri,Uri>(async uri=> 
{
    var content=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    var uris=ProcessThePage(contents);
    return uris;
});


var downloadBlock = new TransformBlock<Uri,(Uri,string)>(async uri=> 
{
    var content=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return (uri,content);
});

var processingBlock = new ActionBlock<(Uri uri,string content)>(async msg=> 
{
    //Do something
    var pathFromUri(msg.uri);
    File.WriteAllText(pathFromUri,msg.content);
});

var linkOptions=new DataflowLinkOptions{PropagateCompletion=true};

listBlock.LinkTo(downloadBlock,linkOptions);    
downloadBlock.LinkTo(processingBlock,linkOptions);
```

Each block runs using its own Task. You can specify that a block may use more than one tasks, eg to download multiple pages concurrently.

Each block has an input and output buffer. You can specify a limit to the input buffer to avoid flooding a block with too many messages to process. If a block reaches the limit upstream blocks will pause. This way, you could prevent eg the `downloadBlock` from flooding a slow `processingBlock` with thousands of pages.

Once you have a pipeline, you can post messages to the first block. When you're done, you can tell the block to Complete(). Each block in the pipeline will finish processing messages in its input buffer and propagate the completion call to the next linked block.

You can await for all messages to finish by awaiting the last block's `Completion` task.

```
var directoryPages=new Uri[]{..};

foreach(var uri in directoryPages)
{
    listBlock.Post(uri);
}

listBlock.Complete();

await processingBlock.Complete();
```

The [ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can be used to specify the use of multiple tasks and the intput buffer limits, eg :

```
var options=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions 
            {
                BoundedCapacity=10, 
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism=4,
            };

var downloadBlock = new TransformBlock<Uri,(Uri,string)>(...,options);
```

This means that `downloadBlock` will accept up to 10 URIs before signalling the `listBlock` to pause. It will process up to 4 Uris concurrently